# Make API Management Portal site multi-languages

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm trying to make my site multi languages. Because of the fact that API managemenet portal site is using paperbits, I thought it is possible to do that.
I found below code in config.design.json file in api managemenet portal site repo.

```json
{
    "environment": "development",
    "managementApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxx.management.azure-api.net",
    "managementApiAccessToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "backendUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.developer.azure-api.net",
    "useHipCaptcha": false,
}
```

In config.design.json file of paperbits demo app, it looks like below.

```json
{
    "firebase": {
        "apiKey": "< your API key >",
        "authDomain": "< your domain >.firebaseapp.com",
        "databaseURL": "https://< your database URL >.firebaseio.com",
        "projectId": "< your project ID >",
        "storageBucket": "< your storage bucket >.appspot.com",
        "databaseRootKey": "/",
        "storageBasePath": "/",
        "auth": {
            "basic": {
                "email": "< user email >",
                "password": "< user password >"
            }  
        }
    },
    "features": {
        "seo": true,
        "localization": true,
        "preview": true
    },
    "environment": "design"
}
```

I found that localization feature exists only in paperbits.

```json
"features": {
        "seo": true,
        "localization": true,
        "preview": true
}
```

So, I add above code on api managemenet portal config.design.json file as well.

Finally, I could modify site on GUI with multi locals and languages.
However, once I change the text on one-language site, another language version of it changes automatically.

Plus after publishing it, I could not see any changes on dist file and could not find any page for another language which I added.
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There's an open issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/137

> Can we have a multilingual dev portal? Is this supported?

[Current status](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/137#issuecomment-1129301729) from 2022-05-09:

> this feature is on our roadmap, but we won't be able to work on it in the next 6 months.

Comment: Thanks for answering!!!

I am trying to self host it. If I could make static content multiligual, it will be fine. Don't have to make dynamic data multilingual. I'm searching how to make static content multilingual. where to modify.

Comment: Appriciate it. I resolved this issue by hosting the applocation own self and modifying modules to connect to the blob stoage storing design and text data.(forgot to reply)